# Need to translate one value into another value from a list

Tags: google-apps-script

Full disclosure - not a programmer...I've just messed a good bit with Excel and Google Sheets, and am stuck trying to find a simple way to transform a specific set of data. Essentially, we have a website host who provides us with the ability to run an export of the results of various fillable forms. One of them is a registration for e-learning videos. The results of the form provide a specific url for each of about 20 videos we maintain...but neither the url or anything in the form itself automatically indicate a human readable label (like "Intro to Application Use") that's useful if someone wants to use the export track what customer has viewed what specific video. So, for each export I do of the data, I need to find a way to run a macro or script that will run through one column of the data, check it against a key that includes each video-specific url, and then spit out a user-readable name for each video into a second column.

So, I need a script that says, if A1:A100=a,b,c,d,e,f,g ("a,b,c,d,e,f,g" being any entry from a list or urls), then set B1:B100=a*,b*,c*,d*,e*,f*,g* ("a*,b*,c*,d*,e*,f*,g*" being the user readable name of each video represented by the urls).

Any thoughts on this? I think I have a way to do it within a formula in all cells in column B, but I'd be referencing so many lengthy urls in that single formula that it seems absurd not to handle it with a script. I'm just a deadbeat when it comes to scripting...

Comment: Hi. I can see you've not had any comments or suggested answers. Have you resolved your issues or are you still looking for assistance?

Comment: Nope, not resolved anything at this point. I have a sloppy, cumbersome way to accomplish this if necessary, but was hoping to hear from someone out here to simplify it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The Questioner is essentially looking for a means to match a meaningful Movie Title to an un-meaningful (but consistent) url provided by a web service. The Questioner says that they have 100 titles though we have no indication of the volume of transactions. Under the circumstances, and without knowing further volumes, the most efficient option is a linear search.

I created a spreadsheet with two sheets:
1 - **Titles:** Contains a list of the Supplier URL and the associated meaningful "Title Name". This is a sheet that would be maintained by the questioner as Titles are added or dropped.
2 - **Transdata:** Contains some same data; includes the Supplier URL, and a column set-aside for the meaningful Title name.

The script involves a nested loop. The first level goes through each row of transaction data. The second, nested loop, evaluates the url for each transaction row and returns the Title, which is saved to the sheet in the "MovieName" Column.

To make it easier to process the function, I've added an OnOpen function so that the Questioner can access the main menu to determine when they process.

---

```
function so_52892546() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var Titles = ss.getSheetByName("Titles");
    var Titlesrange = Titles.getDataRange();
    var Titlesvalues = Titlesrange.getValues();
    var TitleslastRow = Titles.getLastRow();

    var Trans = ss.getSheetByName("TransData");
    var Transrange = Trans.getDataRange();
    var Transvalues = Transrange.getValues();
    var TranslastRow = Trans.getLastRow();

    for (var i = 1; i < TranslastRow; i++) {
        for (var z = 1; z < TitleslastRow; z++) {
            if (Transvalues[i][0] == Titlesvalues[z][0]) {
                var Title = Titlesvalues[z][1];
                //Logger.log("match i = "+1);
            }
        }
        //Logger.log("i="+i+". Title: "+MovieTitle+", date = "+Transdata[i][1]+", income"+Moviesdata[i][2]);
        var targetrange = Trans.getRange(i + 1, 4);
        targetrange.setValue(Title);
    }
}

function onOpen() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var menuItems = [{
        name: 'Update Movie names',
        functionName: 'so_52892546'
    }, ];
    spreadsheet.addMenu('Update Movies', menuItems);
```

---

Screenshot of the Titles sheet
[image: Titles sheet]

---

"Before" and "After" screenshots of the Transdata sheet.
[image: Transdata - Before]

[image: Transdata - After]